# ModRewrite Pattern string matching

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, flags

can somone explain me the ^/ meaning in this pattern ([^/]+)? Is the ^ an negation flag for / and what would be the result if the ^ stand behind the / like /^?

My second question is why match these pattern on several strings without any flag like . <- point etc.?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: your second question is unclear for me.

Comment: My second questions was for example:
String `abc123-321cba/`
Pattern ([^/]+)
Matching abc123-321cba
I don't understand why in this matching group () is no need for a substitute character like `.` <- point to match anything without /.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`([^/]+)?` Optional capturing group with a negated character class matches any character but not of `/` forward slash one or more times.

If `^` present at the start of a character class, then it would do negation. If it's at the middle or at the end like `[/^]`, then it would acts like  a normal character class which matches literal `/` or `^` symbols.

Comment: So `[]` is equivalent to `[.]` in case that no character is defined in group? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `[]` is a wrong because regex won't allow an empty character class. And this `[.]` matches a literal dot.